# Is there a way to have a document be copied and sent to an "outside" location when uploaded?

Tags: 2007, document-library, workflow

Is there an OOTB way for a document to be copied to an external location when it is uploaded to SharePoint?  I know I can create a workflow to do this, but I would like to see if there is a way to do this without having to go to coding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no OOTB way.  A workflow or event receiver are your only options...or perhaps a third-party solution.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much but wanted to make sure before I started making a custom solution.